# How to Create a document in birt using the redis

Tags: redis, birt

I want to know how to create document in `birt` using `redis`.

When data is input to the `redis`, Is it possible to call a *procedure* in `birt`?

Otherwise Is is good if birt have to check queue of redis?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Redis datasource for the most recent version of birt (4.5).  You can either create a Scripted Datasource that talks directly redis (via Java using a Jedis java client library for instance) or a web API that exposes Redis.  A Pojo datasource might work as well.